# Xamarin Forms Binding

Tags: binding, xamarin.forms

Please can anyone tell what does "{Binding .}" mean? The point refers to what? I know that we have refer to a property but I don't understand when I have to put this point

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{Binding}` in XAML is a markup extension, specifically, it's [`BindingExtension`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.BindingExtension/)

If you look at this class, you'll see that it has a `Path` property. In XAML you use it like this:

`{Binding Path=PathThePublicPropertyOfTheBindingContext}` or, shorter by omitting `Path=`:

`{Binding PathThePublicPropertyOfTheBindingContext}`

If the object you want to bind to does not have a property you bind to, but you rather want to bind to the object itself, you use `.`. Say, your binding context is a `string` type:

```cs
public string MyObject = "Hello World";
BindingContext = MyObject;
```

and in XAML

```xml
<Label Text="{Binding .}">
```

it would display "Hello World", the content of the object itself.

Comment: Note that the "." is optional here. You can write `{Binding}` for a binding to self.